# Looking for Baby Monitors with Mobile App and Device

Tags: safety, supervision

I'm looking for a baby monitor that comes with both a monitor device that I can use to view it and also the option to download a mobile app that can view it via a mobile (over Wifi).

I have googled it to death with no luck. It would give me the option to use my phone to see when baby cries as well as a device for convenience to leave downstairs if I don't bring my mobile with me, or for others to use without having to give my phone or wifi password away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a "smart baby monitor".

However, asking to have a baby monitor that comes with both a proprietary viewing device  **and** and mobile app is probably asking too much from the manufacturers.

Developing hardware to view the baby monitors requires the manufacturer to have:

- More materials costs
- Increased engineering costs for developing the hardware
- Software development costs for developing the software
- More limiting computing constraints based on need for minimum-spec hardware

Developing an application for smartphones is seen as an *alternative* to physical devices. You're already providing/own the hardware (why may be better than the hardware they produced), so they can put their resources into the software development aspect of the viewing app.

Since apps are an alternative to, rather than a supplement for, proprietary hardware I'd be impressed if any such products exist.

Even if such a product existed, the dedicated viewing device would most likely have less features and feel terribly basic when compared to the app.

However, you can get your solution yourself just by looking for a smart baby monitor.

Searching Amazon, for instance, with those terms brings up at least 4 monitors with Android/iOS apps in the first 10 hits.

Brands listed include:

- Withings
- iBaby
- VideoSecu
- WiFi Baby
- Medisana

Of the models I quickly found, they have a wide variety of features, so make sure you're looking for other features than just being Android/iOS. Some features are:

- Pan and tilt
- 360 rotation
- Night vision
- 2-way audio
- Video recording
- Snapshots
- Multiple users (AKA, more than 1 smart device can be used to view the monitor)
- App support (how old is the app? Is it being updated regularly?)
- Minimum requirements for the app

  Some smart baby monitors don't come with apps, but have proprietary handheld video monitors and web-based features that make them "smart", so be aware that calling it a *smart* monitor can mean different things. However, this should at least guide you to finding a device.

  To get your 2nd device that you can leave downstairs, you can simply purchase or acquire another smart device. You can buy a pre-paid carrier phone and *not* use it as a phone at all, and use only the baby monitor app. There's a wide variety of low-cost tablets available these days. You may also already have old smart phones you haven't recycled that can be used.

  While this may seem like an additional expense, I would argue that it's probably not any more expensive than a product that would have both a dedicated viewer and a mobile app.

Economically speaking, it's in no one's best interest for a manufacturer to provide both.

Comment: I don't even think it's economics. It just isn't useful to have both from a consumer perspective. Everyone had smartphones and tablets. No need for dedicated monitors plus an app anyways.

Comment: @dpollitt That's still economics. It's not useful to have both, so the company would be spending money creating an unnecessary product that most consumers wouldn't want. The product would then need to cost more than consumers would want to pay. Else, the quality of the product would have to go down to lower manufacturing costs and then they've got other demand issues.

Comment: You are right I have come to the same conclusion, whilst it is useful for me, most manufacturers and customers are not going to see the need of both.

Comment: Buy a cheap second-hand cell phone or tablet, and set it up as a dedicated monitor.

Comment: A word of warning to everyone using such devices; many are horribly insecure. See https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2018/10/16/how-to-buy-and-set-up-a-safe-and-secure-baby-monitor/

Answer (score 2):

We've used Lorex monitors for years.  They can broadcast to Skype. Their hardware tends to be a little fragile, but otherwise works well.

This looks like the new model...
[http://www.amazon.com/Lorex-LW2731-Recording-Monitor-Wireless/dp/B00ARJQRLU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ARJQRLU)

We use this older model, which has a dedicated monitor, but no mobile app.
[http://www.amazon.com/Lorex-LW2031-connect-Wireless-Monitor/dp/B005GTNZU2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GTNZU2)

Comment: Thanks but there is no dedicated receiving device like baby monitors have? I wanted one that provides a device, as well as an app.

Comment: Gotcha. The old model -- which is the one we use -- has a receiving monitor. And it also has a Skype integration. 
I suspect these are a dying breed, since it's probably cheaper for manufacturers to build mobile apps.
http://www.amazon.com/Lorex-LW2031-connect-Wireless-Monitor/dp/B005GTNZU2

Answer (score 1):

You could use any ip camera(such as a foscam or drop cam) and simply buy a low cost tablet as the monitor device.

Any Android or iPad device would do the trick. Amazon kindle fire for example is very low cost and would work with any ip camera. Or you may already have an old iPod touch or tablet that you don't use or could be used for this that would cost you nothing.

Comment: Thanks but there is no dedicated receiving device like baby monitors have? I wanted one that provides a device, as well as an app.

Comment: A dedicated receiving device would provide no advantage. Why would you prefer it?  Buy a Kindle Fire HD brand new for $99 and use *as* a dedicated receiving device if you think that is a benefit.

Comment: Agree with this. I've been using tinycam pro with a couple regular ip cams, and we just have a tablet that is largely dedicated to this purpose. I highly suggest going for 720p (or "megapixel") - the quality is just that much better. Nice part about using a regular cam is it is useful as a regular ip camera after it's not useful for baby anymore (garage monitor, watch automatic cat feeder while away, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The KODAK Cherish C525 Video Baby Monitor comes with a handheld device of it's own and also has an app you can download onto a mobile device to view the video footage from as well.
It's the only one I've been able to find that has both.